# Statically calling methods causes not being able to reference $this within called class?

Tags: php, oop, methods, static-methods

I don't usually call methods statically but since working with the Yii framework I have started to more.

I'm experiencing an issue which I haven't come across before, I am doing this from a `SignupForm` class:

```
$send = mail::sendMail($email_data);
```

..inside the `sendMail` method which is obviously inside the `mail` class I have this line:

```
$email_data['message'] = $this->sanitizeMsg($email_data['message']);
```

The `sanitizeMsg` is a method of the `mail` class and hence that's why I thought referencing it via `$this` should work.

However I am getting the error:

```
Calling unknown method: app\models\SignupForm::sanitizeMsg()
```

Why is it looking for it in the `SignupForm` class? Does this have something to do with me calling it statically? Do I need to revert to using `self::` instead or should I stop calling it statically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$this` only works for member methods. I.e. you can only use it from an instance of the class and I believe also only to access instance members.

To access static members, you should use `self::`.

---

Not familiar with the Yii framework, but what someone does is to use static methods as factory methods. Maybe that's what you're confused by. The static method then creates a new instance of itself and returns it, and inside that instance you can of course use `$this`, but not in the static method. Static methods have no `$this`.

Comment: Hmmm ok. So basically there is no `$this` for either `methods` or `properties` unless you create an instance via `$foo = new bar();` ?

Comment: @Brett Correct. `$this` is only applicable to an instance, so if you don't have an instance, there is no `$this`.